# Create a shake animation for a UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uialertview

I'm trying to make a `UIAlertView` shake. I already made the `alertView` to stay on button click, but the shake animation is not working. Here is what I have:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        self.direction = 1;
        self.shakes = 0;
        [self shake:aUIView];
    }
}

-(void)shake:(UIAlertView *)theOneYouWannaShake
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.03 animations:^ {
                                    theOneYouWannaShake.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(5 * self.direction, 0);
                                  } 
                                  completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                    if(self.shakes >= 10) {
                                      theOneYouWannaShake.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                                      return;
                                    }
                                    self.shakes++;
                                    self.direction = self.direction * -1;
                                    [self shake:theOneYouWannaShake];
                                  }];
}
```

I tried putting an `NSLog` in `- (void)shake...` and I got an output. So there must be something wrong with my code as to why the `alertView` isn't shaking.

Comment: Again you will have to subclass your UIView/AlertView or use this 

https://github.com/lukestringer90/ShakingAlertView library

Comment: @user3693546 I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Are you referencing the whole screen to shake or just the AlertView?

Comment: Just the `alertView`

Comment: @Jessica see answer Jessy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a illusion that makes alertview appear like it is shaking. Provided you must set the parameters about upto how much extent alertview(including that dark background screen) should shake.

Since you can't alter with the frames of UIAlertView so go down on CGTranformations.

```
UIAlertView *dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                 message:@"Message:"
                                                delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];

[dialog setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[dialog show];


UIView *dillusionView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[dillusionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.view addSubview:dillusionView];


[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        dialog.window.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(dialog.transform, dialog.frame.origin.x - 10, dialog.frame.origin.y);
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        dialog.window.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(dialog.transform, dialog.frame.origin.x + 10, dialog.frame.origin.y);
    }];
} completion:nil];
```

I would recommend using Custom created UIAlertView instead, also there are few opensource libraries available.

Comment: Do you mean I should make it from scratch, (from a UIView)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **UIKit Dynamics** for animated effects in iOS. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/introduction-to-uikit-dynamics/) which using **UIKit Dynamics** for `UIAlertView` shake animation. For more you can refer this  [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-uikit-dynamics-swift-animate-apps/)  also which is in swift.