# Shake Animation for UIAlertView in swfit

Tags: animation, swift2, uialertview, ios9.1

I know that there are some similar question on this for Objective-C. Does anybody know how to make it in Swift? Below is my `alertView` function.

```
func alertError(errorString: String?){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error Detected", message:
        errorString, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
        handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: can you tell me when you want to animate alertview ??

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798811/create-a-shake-animation-for-a-uialertview) and [converting](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code) the code in the accepted answer, here is what I got:

```
var dialog: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Title", message: "Message:", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "Done", nil)
dialog.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput
dialog.show()
var dillusionView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height))
dillusionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
view.addSubview(dillusionView)

UIView(duration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat, animations: {    UIView(relativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: { dialog.window.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(dialog.transform, dialog.frame.origin.x - 10, dialog.frame.origin.y)

})
    UIView(relativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: { dialog.window.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(dialog.transform, dialog.frame.origin.x + 10, dialog.frame.origin.y)

    })

}, completion: nil)
```

As a warning there could be some bugs in this code. Hope it helps!